# Example of $f,g: [0,1]\to[0,1]$ and Riemann-integrable, but $g\circ f$ is not?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, examples-counterexamples, riemann-integration

Give me an example of two Riemann-integrable functions $f,g:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ such that $g\circ f$ isn't integrable! 
I already know the following example:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0,     &     \text{if $x$ is irrational} \\
1,     &     \text{if $x=0$}\\
\frac1q, &     \text{if $x$ is rational and $x=\frac pq$ such that $q\in\Bbb N$ and $(p,q)=1$}  \\
\end{cases}$$
$$g(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x$ is of the form $\frac 1q$such that $q\in \Bbb N$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}  \\
\end{cases}$$
now observe that $g\circ f$ is a famous example of non-integrable function!

Comment: As it turns out, this particular $f$ and $g$ are not a great example--when you extend the definition of the integral to include more functions, $g \circ f$ integrates fine.

Comment: Extend to what??

Comment: [Lebesgue integration!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration)  The integral of $g \circ f$ turns out to be $0$.

Comment: Can someone explain why f is integrable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More simply, sticking with the same $f$ you may consider 
$$g(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x=0$} \\
1, & \text{if $x\in ]0,1]$}  \\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: in this case$g\circ f$ is integrable!

Comment: Nope it is not ! I'll provide proof if you're not persuaded.

Comment: excuse me your answer is true and simpler thanks!!

Comment: You seem to like exclamation points!!!!!